# Binomials (a) 8!/6! (b) 10!/9!

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I don't know the exact formula to use for this expansion I have tried to use multiple equations so therefore there must be one you can use.

Comment: Did you try the definition of factorial? $n! = n*n-1*...*2*1$

Comment: How would it work for a binomial as a fraction like the ones given in the question.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hint: $8!=(8)(7)(6!)$.

Answer (score 2):

For an integer $n$, $n!$ is defined as the product of all positive integers $\le n$ or equivalently as $n*(n-1)!$ and $0!$ is defined as $1$. Use these definitions.